# If statements based on url

Tags: php

I'm attempting to show a div tag based on the root url of my site i.e. if the url is dev.foo.com display div if else www.foo.com don't display etc. I've come up with this

```
<?php if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 5) !== 'dev.') {
    echo '<div class="dev-site-stuff">THIS IS THE DEV SITE!!</div>';
}
 ?>
```

But it isn't working and I can't see a reason - any thoughts greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's a '(!==)? It's either equal to ('==') or not equal to ('!=')

Comment: @AR: `!==` is the inverse of `===`.  In PHP (and a few other languages), the triple equals compares type as well as value.

Comment: AR, you're wrong. From experience I have found it's better to check before you tell someone they don't know what they're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 2);

/* you might want pretty variable that exactly gets the subdomain.
 * $subdomain = $url[0] != "www" ? $url[0] : "";
 * if($subdomain == "dev") {
 *   // dev site...
 * }else if($subdomain == "") {
 *   // www site...
 * }
 */

if($url[0] == "dev") {
  echo '<div class="dev-site-stuff">THIS IS THE DEV SITE!!</div>';
}
```

substr, strpos etc. are not always effective in this cases. It's nice?

EDIT: By the way read comments of your question.

Answer (score 6):

you should use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

If you have any other doubts just do a `print_r($_SERVER);` to actually see how the array is composed

Comment: For additional detail on each key, [check the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: This assumes the dev and live sites are on different servers

Comment: @user: never heard of virtual host?

Comment: ever notice how the OP didn't specify their configuration?

Answer (score 1):

As well as @yes123 answer above you are also comparing a substring of length 5 against a string of length 4 so it will never be true.

You con use strrpos like this

```
 if (strrpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 'dev.') > 0) {
```

Hope this helps.